# VBS File List with author attribute

Tags: vbscript

I have a VBS list script to list file,with various dates. All of the files are MS Word documents but I want the AUTHOR from the document attributes (I tried googling "author" attribute not the best search).

I am after a text list of all the documents in a folder :- File name , date accessed, date created, date modified and AUTHOR. I was hoping VBS would crack it but if there is another solution out there I am open to suggestions.

```
On Error Resume Next

Const WINDOW_HANDLE = 0
Const BIF_EDITBOX = &H10
Const BIF_NONEWFOLDER = &H0200
Const BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS = &H1

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'**Browse For Folder To Be Processed
strPrompt = "Please select the folder to process."
intOptions = BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS + BIF_NONEWFOLDER + BIF_EDITBOX
strTargetPath = wshShell.SpecialFolders("MyDocuments")
strFolderPath = Browse4Folder(strPrompt, intOptions, strTargetPath)

Set objNewFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strFolderPath & "\filelist.txt", True)
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolderPath)
Set objColFiles = objFolder.Files

For Each file In objColFiles
    objNewFile.WriteLine(file.Name)
    objNewFile.WriteLine(file.DateCreated)
    objNewFile.WriteLine(file.DateLastAccessed)
    objNewFile.WriteLine(file.DateLastModified)
Next
objNewFile.Close

'**Browse4Folder Function
Function Browse4Folder(strPrompt, intOptions, strRoot)
    Dim objFolder, objFolderItem

    On Error Resume Next

    Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, strPrompt, intOptions, strRoot)
    If (objFolder Is Nothing) Then
        Wscript.Quit
    End If
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
    Browse4Folder = objFolderItem.Path
    Set objFolderItem = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to go through the properties of the Word Application object.

Look [here](http://access.mvps.org/access/modules/mdl0003.htm) for instance how to do that.

Should be something like this:

```
Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open("myWordDocument.doc")
Set sAuthor = oDoc.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Author")
```